# Embedded Ruby Inline Styling HAML

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

In Rails, I am using ERB to create dynamic CSS for a background-image. For instance, I use the following line of code:

```
<nav class="nav" style='background: url(<%= image_path("nav-background.png") %>);'>
```

which renders the appropriate `image_path` for this HTML element. How would I accomplish this in HAML?

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
%body{:style => 'background: url(= image_path("beige_paper.png"));'}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to interpolate the `image_path` within the `style` value:

```
%body{:style => "background: url(#{image_path('beige_paper.png')});"}
```

Make sure your value of `:style` is in double-quotes and the `image_path` value is in single-quotes for the interpolation to work properly.